# the proof for rule of limit of functions

Tags: limits

I've seen these formulas but I don't know what the proof is.
If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ ,$\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=K$ therefore: $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)=KL$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)+g(x)=K+L$
these are obvious but I want to know the mathematical proof
I have no idea what to do.can anybody help?

Comment: You'd have to be okay with the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of limit.  Are you?

Comment: Yes I'm OK with that.

Comment: Ah, then it is certainly within your reach.  The proofs of these are pretty standard, and I would bet any book you found would have the same argument.  (I would also bet someone here would post a good answer in due time.)

Comment: As you mentioned these results are obvious and if one understands the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition of a limit then getting at a proof is not difficult. Thus for the simpler theorem dealing with $K+L$ think of the definition of limit for the function $f(x) +g(x) $ and it's purported limit $K+L$. You will have to analyze the expression $|f(x) +g(x) - (K+L) |$ and see if it can be made smaller than arbitrary positive $\epsilon$.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Proofs_of_Some_Basic_Limit_Rules